Getting an Undefined Value error in Google Script Function
The 'Ensure columnReference is a valid number' section of the Google Script code below evaluates to true, even though I'm calling the function with a value that is clearly a number. I'm new to javascript, so any insight would be most appreciated.
getColumnValuesWithRename(5);

function getColumnValuesWithRename(columnReference) {
  // Get the sheet by name
  let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('References');
  
  // Check if the sheet exists
  if (!sheet) {
    Logger.log("Sheet 'References' not found.");
    return; // Exit the function
  }
  
  // Ensure columnReference is a valid number
  if (typeof columnReference !== 'number' || columnReference < 1) {
    Logger.log("Invalid columnReference value: " + columnReference);
    return; // Exit if columnReference is invalid
  }
  
  // Get the range and log the values
  const columnValues = sheet.getRange(1, columnReference, 1000, 1).getValues();
  Logger.log(columnValues); // Log the retrieved values
}



Replace
getColumnValuesWithRename(5);

by
function main(){
  getColumnValuesWithRename(5);
}

Then, before clicking Run, ensure that the dropdown next to this button displays main. Otherwise, first select main, then click Run.

The code shown the question seems fine. Chances are that your script project contains another function that has the same name, and you are actually seeing the output from that other copy. When there is more than one function with the same name, JavaScript will use the version that is declared last.
You can make the issue visible by declaring the function as an arrow function, like this:
const getColumnValuesWithRename = (columnReference) => {
  if (typeof columnReference !== 'number' || columnReference < 1) {
    console.log("Invalid columnReference value: " + columnReference);
  } else {
    console.log(`typeof columnReference: ${typeof columnReference}`);    
  }
}

getColumnValuesWithRename(5);

If there is no duplicate declaration, the code will log:
typeof columnReference: number.
If there is a duplicate declaration, JavaScript will throw an error:
Error: Identifier 'getColumnValuesWithRename' has already been declared.
See Which function runs, Apps Script debugging and How to debug small programs.

The OP clicks Run with getColumnValuesWithRename displayed in the dropdown, so the function is run twice.

@Wicket got it — that makes the question like "caused by a typo."

Thanks for replying. Regarding the vote to close, I disagree as I see this to be about tools frequently used by programmers, in this case, the Google Apps Script online code editor.

It's a "code" question. Nothing is asked regarding dev tools. I continue to think it's like "caused by a typo."
